# Move Folders and files from folders/subfolders with same name (copies to be renamed)

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory, rename

(I have tried to rewrite this to be more clear)

I have a problem with having hundreds of folders and files (each start with ABC and then numbers 001-936) that need to be moved to a single folder with the same name. For example:

```
C:\folders\ABC001 
C:\folders\random\ABC001\ 
C:\folders\files\ABC001.pdf 
C:\folders\ABC002.pdf 
C:\folders\ABC002\  
C:\folders\needs sorting\ABC002\
```

That I would like to move all files and folders to a folder with the same name:

```
C:\folders\ABC\ABC001\ 
C:\folders\ABC\ABC002\  
and so on...
```

However, sometimes the orginal folder and/or file will have a duplicate in the destination folder(or may already have since folders already exist), so I want it to add to the name (1), (2), etc.

```
C:\folders\ABC\ABC001\ABC001\
C:\folders\ABC\ABC001\ABC001 (1)\ 
C:\folders\ABC\ABC001\ABC001.pdf 
C:\folders\ABC\ABC002\ABC002.pdf 
C:\folders\ABC\ABC002\ABC002\  
C:\folders\ABC\ABC002\ABC002 (1)\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to solve this for weeks (everytime I needed the files) but am new to scripting/code. I started with:

```
for /R "C:\folders" %x in (*abc123*.*) do move "%x" "D:\folders\abc\abc123"
```

Closest attempt (minor edits to another code):

```
function MoveFileToFolder ([string]$source,[string]$destination){
# get a list of source files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | ?{($_.PSIsContainer)}
# verify if the list of source files is empty
if ($files -ne $null) {
    foreach ($file in $files) {
    $filename = $file.Name
    $filebase = $file.BaseName
    $fileext = $file.Extension
# verify if destination file exists
    $filenameNU = $filename 
    if (Test-Path (Join-Path $destination $filename)) {
        $n = 0
        while ((Test-Path (Join-Path $destination $filenameNU)) -eq $true)
        {
        $filenameNU = $filebase + "(" + ++$n + ")" + $fileext
        }
    }
    Move-Item $file.FullName (Join-Path $destination $filenameNU)
    }
}
}

MoveFileToFolder C:\folders\ C:\folders\abc\abc123
```

(I would try and run this in Powershell for each subfolder, but it became very hard to keep up with)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome as a (quite) new user to [SO]. I'm in doubt if I have a deja vue or a flash back with this same recurring question. I wouldn't move a folder with an appended number **inside** it's sibling, but side by side. Also before appending numbers for files I'd first check for equality by comparing `Get-FileHash` an delte one or create a hard-/softlink.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is that the folders are automatically saved by another device from another company, so I cannot change the naming scheme. Also, the folders contain data that is not identifiable without opening each file. I can move the folders side by side, but still would have difficulty with how to accomplish that...